# Using gethostbyname() function on an external device

Tags: c, ssh

I'm using the client server program in C language on a Linux OS. In a first step, I programmed the code on the same machine using "localhost". Therefore, for the client to get the server information, I would use

> server = gethostbyname("localhost")

since both the client and the server are running on the same machine.

However, now I would like to connect to an external device (using ssh). The device's username is of the following type

> user@foxboard1

Although, I am not sure how to use the gethostbyname() function in this instance. I have tried

> server = gethostbyname("user@foxboard1")

but that doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

P.s, I cannot copy and paste the code since it's on a different machine

**EDIT**

Instead of retreiving information about an external device, I would like to connect to the device using its IP address (an ssh connection through the `connect()` function.

Comment: BTW: You should use `getaddrinfo()` resp. `getnameinfo()` instead of `gethostbyname()`.

Comment: Maybe I did not get the point of your question, but obviously "user@foxboard1" is _not_ a hostname, so nothing that can be resolved by a name resolution function. "foxboard1" might be a hostname, so might be resolvable (depends on your environment), so that substring _might_ be resolvable. So use string manipulation to tell username and hostname apart.

Comment: @glglgl Could you tell me how to use either function in that case because I see they both return integer values when I want a string to be returned.

Comment: @arkascha Well, in conclusion, how do I connect to a user device (i.e what function should I use)?

Comment: Sorry, but that is a totally different thing. Now is your question about name resolution or about "remote connection"? You asked why your `gethostbyname()` call does not work. I explained that.

Comment: Well now I realize why gethostbyname() didn't work, because I'm trying to conenct to a user which isn't a name. So my next question is how do I connect to a user, or which function do I use?

Comment: @JohnSmith To be clear, it was not supposed to be a solution to your problem (that's why I commented), but you should read their documentation. And: What exactly do you want? An address? Or a string? Which kind of string? `gethostbyname()` doesn't give you a string as well...

Comment: @glglgl Thanks to your comment I was able to look at their documentation, but the functions take in a lot of argument values that I'm not sure I understand. In any case, I want a function that returns a structure of type hostent, much like gethostbyname().

Comment: @JohnSmith About your edit: Between `connect()` - which gives you a pure TCP/IP connection - and a working SSH connection there is a lot of effort needed. So it would probably better to use external commands for that. Could you descripe what you are actually up to on the remote machine? Sending data, receiving data, starting programs, ...?

Comment: On the remote machine (ie the client) it's main purpose is to send data for the server (the external device) to calculate. Once the device has done the calculations, it returns (sends back) the result to the client.

Comment: Actually, I have just solved my issue. Instead of changing the function alltogether, I simply replace "localhost" by the IP address of the device! I'd like to thank all of you for helping me out!

Comment: @JohnSmith But then you don't have a SSH connection yet...

Comment: @glglgl I do because I specify the port number in which the connection should be made.

Comment: @JohnSmith I don't understand that. SSH is not just setting a port number. I explained already what it means. But if it works for you, it is fine, even if it is not SSH.

Comment: @glglgl I'm sorry, maybe I misunderstood your comment and/or the whole concept of SSH. But I think maybe my question wasn't very clear in the first place. I'd like to thank you nonetheless for your constant help!

Answer (score 0):

`gethostbyname()` and its replacement `getaddrinfo()` are supposed to transform a host name or strin representation of an IP address into a "usable" structure.

This works very well on things like `localhost`, `www.google.com`, `1.2.3.4` etc.

But if you have a username embedded in the string, you'll have to split them up.

Of course, you'll have to become aware what kind of connection you want to establish and what the username is useful for.

If, as it seems, you want to do a SSH connection, it is probably best to use `popen()` and alike functions to start an external `ssh` process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although, I'm not sure how a function of return type FILE* relates to an ssh connection. Would it be possible to tell me how to associate a function of return type hostent* that takes in as an argument the user "user@foxboard1"?

Comment: @JohnSmith These functions translate a host name to an IP address. They don't know anything about that ssh syntax. You can parse that string and pass "foxboard1" to gethostbyname or getaddrinfo to resolve the host if you need to.

Comment: @nos Of course, but that doesn't relieve him from setting up the SSH stack properly, including encryption, authentification, channels and all that stuff.

Comment: @JohnSmith Well, if you have a `FILE *`, you can write anything into it what you would send over to the remote program. Of course, it all depends on what you are actually are planning to do.

Comment: @glglgl True, but how to connect to a machine using ssh is quite a different question from how to use gethostbyname

Comment: Thank you to the both of you for your help! I have solved this issue as stated above. I infact simply replace "localhost" by the IP address of the device (since localhost is nothing but an IP address of the local machine).